# Pygame simple loop runs very slowly on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

**E:** After testing the same on OS X and Linux, I can confirm that the following only happens on OS X. On Linux it literally runs at a thousand fps, as I happened to wonder. Any explanation? I would much prefer developing on Mac, thanks to TextMate.

---

Here's a simple loop that does almost nothing, and still runs very slowly. Can anyone explain why? FPS averages at little over 30, it takes a little over 30ms for each pass over the loop. Window size does not seem to affect this at all, as even setting a tiny window size like (50,50) has the same fps.

I find this weird, I would expect that any contemporary hardware could do a thousand fps for such a simple loop, even when we update every pixel every time. From the profile I can see that `{built-in method get}` and `{built-in method update}` combined seem to take around 30ms of time per call, is that really the best we can get out without using dirty rects?

```
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 1000
#milliseconds from last frame
new_time, old_time = None, None    

done = False

while not done:

    clock.tick(fps)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # show fps and milliseconds
    if new_time:
        old_time = new_time
    new_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if new_time and old_time:
        pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(int(clock.get_fps())) + " ms: " + str(new_time-old_time))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Here's the beginning of a cProfile of the main function.

```
         94503 function calls (92211 primitive calls) in 21.011 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.026    0.026   21.011   21.011 new_main.py:34(main)
      652   14.048    0.022   14.048    0.022 {built-in method get}
      652    5.864    0.009    5.864    0.009 {built-in method update}
        1    0.444    0.444    0.634    0.634 {built-in method init}
      651    0.278    0.000    0.278    0.000 {built-in method set_caption}
     72/1    0.000    0.000    0.151    0.151 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2234(_find_and_load)
     72/1    0.000    0.000    0.151    0.151 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2207(_find_and_load_unlocked)
     71/1    0.000    0.000    0.151    0.151 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1186(_load_unlocked)
     46/1    0.000    0.000    0.151    0.151 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1122(_exec)
     46/1    0.000    0.000    0.151    0.151 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1465(exec_module)
     74/1    0.000    0.000    0.151    0.151 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:313(_call_with_frames_removed)
     54/1    0.004    0.000    0.151    0.151 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.151    0.151 macosx.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.150    0.150 pkgdata.py:18(<module>)
     25/3    0.000    0.000    0.122    0.041 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1156(_load_backward_compatible)
      8/1    0.026    0.003    0.121    0.121 {method 'load_module' of 'zipimport.zipimporter' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.101    0.101 __init__.py:15(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.079    0.079 config_reader.py:115(build_from_config)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.056    0.028 common.py:43(reset_screen)
        2    0.055    0.027    0.055    0.027 {built-in method set_mode}
    72/71    0.001    0.000    0.045    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:2147(_find_spec)
    70/69    0.000    0.000    0.043    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1934(find_spec)
    70/69    0.001    0.000    0.043    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1902(_get_spec)
       92    0.041    0.000    0.041    0.000 {built-in method load_extended}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.041    0.007 new_map.py:74(add_character)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.041    0.007 new_character.py:32(added_to_map)
        6    0.001    0.000    0.041    0.007 new_character.py:265(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.038    0.038 macosx.py:14(Video_AutoInit)
        1    0.038    0.038    0.038    0.038 {built-in method InstallNSApplication}
        1    0.036    0.036    0.036    0.036 {built-in method quit}
       65    0.001    0.000    0.036    0.001 re.py:277(_compile)
       49    0.000    0.000    0.036    0.001 re.py:221(compile)
```

Comment: Even without the update call, my mac will only go to 60 fps.

Comment: Changing the `set_caption` to a print like: `print ("fps: " + str(int(clock.get_fps())) + " ms: " + str(new_time-old_time))` gets me to 60 fps also.

Comment: Also, why isn't 60 fps fast enough?  Your monitor probably can't display any faster than that.

Comment: Just for fun, I tried it in a Windows 7 VM using Fusion, and it was limited to 62 fps.  I don't have a linux machine with pygame to experiment, but I'm guessing it's just lying to you in some fashion.

Comment: Some fps being enough is not the point. The point is, if it only runs even at 60fps, there seems to be something wrong. It should be running at much higher fps, in my opinion.

Comment: Well, you have a right to your opinion, but it's not doing 1000 fps on any platform.  It's lying to you.  Simple as that.

Comment: Okay then. But should it not do higher than 60fps?

Comment: I've never seen it, and I have some very fast machines.  If you really need faster than 60 fps, pygame is probably not the right tool to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this ended up being that the retina display under OS X is the differentiating factor. Running it even on an external display on the same Mac works fine. But moving the window to the retina display makes it sluggish. With or without an external monitor connected.

On the other hand, it runs just fine on the same retina display under Linux. It is unclear what the difference in the display managers / rendering is that causes this, but I doubt there is anything one could do about it.

Comment: We have the exact same problem. Have you ever found a solution to solve this so games will run smooth on the macbook screen itself aswell?

Comment: @Merijndk As far as I know, there's know change in the situation, unfortunately. Still don't know why it happens either.

Comment: well it kind of makes sense since the screen size on ratina is huge. The problem is that python overall is pretty slow on mac. Where i run our app on linux and windows 250fps easily my friends pretty new macbook runs it at 60fps max. Also python will use 100% of his cpu while on my windows it is only 10%. Hope they fix it soon

Answer (score 0):

Changing the game resolution to fullscreen helped me.
Try this:

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

instead of:

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode((winx, winy))
```