# Pygame failing to draw on Mac

Tags: python, macos, graphics, pygame, pycharm

First of all, I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.1 with pygame 1.9.4.

Also, I am using the PyCharm IDE and am using python 3.7.1.

I decided that it would be interesting to try out pygame, but drawing even a simple rectangle or image does not work.

Here is the code I have tried using to draw a rectangle, draw an image that is in the same directory as the file, and fill the window with white. None of which work.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
image = pygame.image.load("java_logo.png")

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        win.fill((0, 255, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (50, 50, 50, 50))
        win.blit(image, (200, 200))
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

**Edit:**

Here was the image used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCqw4.png

Comment: Please provide the image(s) you load in order to make your example complete. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Done!

Comment: Thank you. It's late here, I'll check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, @MarkSetchell. Have you had a chance to look into this yet?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did. I spent an age and couldn't get anything to work at all. It seems there are plenty of folk having issues on Macs from other questions. One person succeeded by making it full-screen, another succeeded like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651218/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I see. That is unfortunate. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known-issue [Pygame not compatible with MacOS Mojave #555](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555)

According to issue's comments it has been fixed in pygame **1.9.5** only

UPD:
It should work for python 3.6.5

Comment: Just realized the bug does not reproduce with python 3.6.5

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same problem than you last night. None window is loading when executing a very simple pygame code, a ball bouncing in a window.
The solution as related by other members is to install a newer version of pygame, in my case install the latest beta version of v2.0 of pygame lib.

Here shell code to install in OS X Mojave with python3 installed.

```
pip3 install pygame=2.0.0.dev6
```

Answer (score 2):

Pygame still not working on Python 3.7.3, pygame 1.9.5, on OS X Mojave 10.14.3

So pygame 1.9.5 does not fix the issue.

In a simple test program (see below) window opens, window caption works, but nothing is drawn.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((612,792))
pygame.display.set_caption("This works!")

red = (255,0,0)
screen.fill(red)

# point (0,0) is at upper left                                                             
pygame.draw.lines(screen,black,False,[(100,100),(150,200),(200,100)], 1)

pygame.display.update() #nothing is drawn

while (True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using python 3.8 and couldn't load images.
Working as expected after `pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev10`

Comment: This worked for me.  All pygame versions ≥ 2.0.0 should be compatible now (https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555) ```pip install pygame --upgrade``` for latest version

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to install Python version 3.6.0 of the Python page after using pip3 install pygame version 1.9.6

that works for me

Answer (score 0):

For me i had to install

> python 3.6
> and
> pygame 1.9.6

on macOS **Mojave 10.14.6** plus I had to add `pygame.display.update()`

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot pygame.display.update() to update the screen.
Also, for pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (50,50,50,50)),
that means that you draw a rectangle with the top-left corner at (50,50)  (first two parts) with a width and length of 50 pixels each. (last two parts).